# Inno Setup でスタートメニューに複数のファイルを表示させる方法

Tags: windows-10, inno-setup

InnoSetupのスクリプトを作成しています。
スタートメニューにヘルプファイルやマニュアルのような実行ファイルと別のファイルを登録したいのですが、記述方法がわかりません。
サンプルのスクリプトファイルを参照しながら作成していますが、理解が追い付きません。
以下のスクリーンショットの赤丸で囲ったような追加をしたいと考えています。
ご存じの方はご教示いただけないでしょうか。

[image: スタートメニューのサンプル]

Comment: `[Icons]`セクションに追記すれば良いけれども勝手に削減されることもあるらしいです。[Inno Setup Create more icons on Start menu (Win10) \[duplicate\] - inno-setup](https://android.developreference.com/article/12339576/Inno+Setup+Create+more+icons+on+Start+menu+(Win10)+%5Bduplicate%5D)

Comment: 毎々、ありがとうございます。試してみます。アンインストーラがWin10の最適化でスタートメニューから排除されるという記載になっていますね。EXE形式以外では大丈夫なのか試してみます。

Comment: 試して出来ましたら自己回答でもしてください。私自身は使ったことが無いので回答を書くのにはあまり適切ではないでしょうから。

Comment: @kunif さんが提示されたリンク先は、StackOverflow からの転載サイトのようです。オリジナルは https://stackoverflow.com/q/49496494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメント欄にて提示していただいたURLを参照して解決いたしました。

[Inno Setup Create more icons on Start menu (Win10) - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49496494)

`#define` による宣言と、`[Icons]` での `{group}` を記述すれば大丈夫でした。
App_id部分を省略したスクリプトのコードは以下の通りです。

```
#define MyAppName "MyApp"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "MyCompany"
#define MyAppExeName "MyApp.exe"
#define AppSrcPath "dist\MyApp"
#define MyAppSetupName "MyApp_setup"
#define MyAppManualName "Manual"
#define MyAppManualPDFName "manual\manual.pdf"

[Setup]
-----
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename={#MyAppSetupName}
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern
SetupIconFile=.\logo\MyApp.ico
UninstallDisplayIcon=.\logo\MyApp.ico

[Languages]
Name: "japanese"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Japanese.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "{#SourcePath}{#AppSrcPath}\MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{#SourcePath}{#AppSrcPath}\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppManualName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppManualPDFName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```